# Problems with atof in C

Tags: c, unix

you could say that I am relatively new to C, but I need clarification on a question.
I have a char[] that represents a number. If this char[] is longer than LONG_MAX I want to tell the user it is too long. The problem is that when I compare its value to a float, it becomes truncated. Here's what I mean.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  char str[] = argv[1]; /* I set it to 9223372036854775809, only +1 higher than LONG_MAX */ 
  double l = atof(str); 
  double j = LONG_MAX; 

  printf("%lf\n", l); /* This prints 9223372036854775808.000000, which is LONG_MAX ??? WHY?? */
  printf("%lf\n", j); /* This prints same as above, 9223372036854775808.000000 */ 

  printf("%s\n", l > j ? "true" : "false"); /* false */

  return 0; /* what am I doing wrong? */

}
```

UPDATE:

I tried your iret solution and I still run into the same rounding problem

```
 j = LONG_MAX; 
  int iret = sscanf (str, "%lf", &l);
  if (iret != 1)
    return 0; /* conversion was bad */
  else {
    if (l > j || l < -(j))
      return 0; /* too small or too large */
  }

  printf("%lf\n", l); 
  printf("%lf\n", j);

  printf("%s\n", l > j ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to a float?

Comment: Where are `l` and `j` defined? And why do they have such terrible names?

Comment: I thought short, terse, terrible names were a part of C. I changed the code to be double, what it was originally. I tried float because it was bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for overflow easily enough with `strtol`, but it requires a little extra work.

```
const char *str = ...;
char *e;
long x;

errno = 0;
x = strtol(str, &e, 0);
if (!*str || *e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid number: %s\n", str);
    exit(1);
}
if ((x == LONG_MAX || x == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "number too large: %s\n", str);
    exit(1);
}
```

Now, let's talk about the problem with `strtod` (or `atof`, which is just a broken version of `strtod`).

If you convert `9223372036854775809` to a `double`, then `9223372036854775808` is **correct**.  A `double` has 53 bits of precision, and a 64-bit `long` has, well, 64 bits.  As soon as you start working with floating-point numbers you need to be prepared for rounding.

For example, there is round-off error in the following code.  Can you spot it?

```
double x = 0.1;
```

**Footnote:** I'm assuming 64-bit `long` and IEEE double-precision `double` here.

Comment: where is errno supposed to get set?

Answer (score 0):

Per the "man" page for atof:

> http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof
>
> The atof() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed
>   to by nptr to double. ... atof() does not detect errors.

Which is why I prefer to use "sscanf" instead:

`int iret = sscanf (SOME_TEXT, "%lf", &SOME_DOUBLE);`

If "iret != 1", then I know an error occurred, and can take the appropriate action.

IMHO...

PS:

Why aren't you declaring "l" and "j".  Naughty naughty!  You should always declare your variables, even in FORTRAN and Basic ;)

And why not declare them as float ("%f") or double ("%lf")?

Comment: You're right, I fixed the declarations. This is just a snippet of the file. Can I compare SOME_DOUBLE to LONG_MAX properly?

Comment: Please see my updates, sscanf still creates an undesirable rounding.

Comment: `sscanf`? How is that different? `sscanf` does not detect overflow errors either. `sscanf` produces undefined behavior on overflow. The only proper way to do this conversion is functions from `strto...` group.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why you are getting the value "9223372036854775808.000000" for both your inputs is due to the precision limitations of floating point approximations.

By the way, the value isn't `LONG_MAX`, but `LONG_MAX + 1 -> 2^63`.

By definition, the representation of `LONG_MAX` exactly (as an integer) requires 63 bits of precision.  However, in a 64-bit floating point representation like `double`, *there are only 53 bits of precision*, since the other bits are required to store the sign and exponent.  That's why both `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MAX + 2` end up being rounded to `9223372036854775808 <=> 2^63`.

To handle this case properly, perhaps look at [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) which will set an error code when the input is out of range.

Comment: `LONG_MAX` only requires 63 bits of precision, not 64.

Comment: @DietrichEpp fair call, but the argument that there are less than 63 bits of precision still stands I think.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, it's the right idea. His long is 63 bits. A float has 23 significant bits. So everything past the upper 23 bits gets cut off. And the two numbers are the same in the upper 23 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your long seems to be 63 bits. A float has 23 significant bits (or 24 with leading 1). Your longs are the exactly the same in the upper 24 bits. So they become the same. 
A float is basically mantissa*2^exponent. The exponent makes sure that the magnitude still matches. But you only have 23 bits of mantissa. So it becomes top23bitsoflong*2^(numberofremainingbits). 
This is a bit simplified ignoring leading one and exponent bias.